# Symfony 2.8 How to include GuzzleHttp as Bundle

Tags: symfony, bundle, symfony-2.8

Guzzle is outdated and so I installed instead via composer the recommended replacement

```
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
```

I checked in the vendor directory and there is  my guzzlehttp lib:
guzzlehttp, although I also still see the old guzzle even after deleting the whole vendor directory and doing composer update again.

However in my Appkernel.php I want to include now guzzlehttp instead of the old eightpoint guzzle as a Bundle and wonder how to do that.

The old syntax was like this:

```
new EightPoints\Bundle\GuzzleBundle\GuzzleBundle(),
```

I tried with

```
new GuzzleHttp\GuzzleBundle(),
```

But it isn't found. Do I miss another step? If yes which one?

Edit:

original composer.json where I want to replace guzzle with the guzzleHttp since  this guzzle package seems to be abandoned:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
    "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "eightpoints/guzzle-bundle": "4.5.*",
    "symfony/finder": "^2.8",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "^1.1",
    "jms/di-extra-bundle": "~1.3",
    "jms/aop-bundle": "~1.1",
    "jms/cg": "~1.1",
    "psr/cache": "~1.0",
    "predis/predis": "1.*",
    "snc/redis-bundle": "2.*",
    "cache/predis-adapter": "*",
    "willdurand/hateoas-bundle": "^1.0",
    "hautelook/templated-uri-bundle": "^2.0",
    "willdurand/rest-extra-bundle": "^1.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^1.7",
    "friendsofsymfony/http-cache-bundle": "^1.0",
    "avtonom/semaphore-bundle": "dev-master",
    "symfony/stopwatch": "*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "*",
    "phpunit/php-invoker": "*",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "*",
    "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "*",
    "diablomedia/phpunit-pretty-printer": "*"
},
```

....

Comment: Look at the platform section of your composer.json.  It is probably set to something like php 3.5.9.  Change it to match your actual php version or just remove it then do a composer update.  The old php platform version is preventing the newer version of guzzle/http from being installed.

Comment: And you have no config:platform:php entry in composer.json?  Changing the require php version is not going to help.

Comment: No I don't have this entry in my composer.json . 
What does the "platform" entry do?

Comment: If present, the platform php version is used to determine which version of dependencies to install.  Out of the box, the S2.8 composer.json file had a value of 5.3.9.  First time I tried a simple composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle I ended up with an old version of guzzle like you did.  Changing it to match my actual php version (7.2.1) got me the latest and greatest guzzle.  If you want I can post my composer.json as a partial answer.

Comment: Very interesting! But I cannot  require other software packages on the system, can I? Only the ones shown by "composer show --platform" ?

Comment: The platform version represents the max php version not the min.  So anything that requires 7.2 or lower can be installed.  For example, "composer require snc/redis-bundle" seems to work as expected and gives me the same 2.0 version you have.  I guess what I am saying is to start a fresh 2.8 project, adjust the platform version and then require your various third party bundles.  If all goes well you can then replace your existing composer.json with the latest working one.

Comment: And by the way, changing the require php version is probably not going to help.  Best to leave it alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Guzzle lib does not provide any Symfony integration. Seems like you are using an old version of EightPointsGuzzleBundle.

Instead of requiring `guzzlehttp/guzzle` which is just a lib,  do `composer require eightpoints/guzzle-bundle` and then in your *AppKernel* add 
`new EightPoints\Bundle\GuzzleBundle\EightPointsGuzzleBundle()`

Maybe you should just update your bundle to a newer version.

Comment: Ah but that will give me the old bundle which is deprecated and which I want to replace.

Comment: this one https://github.com/8p/EightPointsGuzzleBundle is not deprecated

Comment: - Installing eightpoints/guzzle-wsse-middleware (v4.2.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing eightpoints/guzzle-bundle (v6.1.2): Downloading (100%)         
Package guzzle/guzzle is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use guzzlehttp/guzzle instead.

Comment: can you please update your question and provide your composer.json requirements ?

Comment: see update. This is the original composer.json 
With this configuration I always get the message: 
"Package guzzle/guzzle is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use guzzlehttp/guzzle instead."

Comment: I did that, but I have now problems with integrating the guzzle client into my service. 
Before I had in the services.yml '@guzzle.client' as a parameter and now no variation I tried so far works. I followed the other instructions in the UPGRADE.md document.

What I tried so far:

'@eight_points_guzzle.http_client'

'@eight_points_guzzle.client'

'@guzzle.client'

'@eight_points_guzzle.client.class'

But no success. Any suggestions?

Comment: is your bundle correctly registrered in your AppKernel file ?

Comment: yes, according to the docu I updated to:
new EightPoints\Bundle\GuzzleBundle\EightPointsGuzzleBundle()

I also updated  the config.yml    
eight_points_guzzle:
            class: GuzzleHttp\Client

Comment: I did the same update in another symfony 2.8 software project of mine. There I got so far no problems with tests and cache clear, but I didn't use guzzle in any service there.

Looks like the problem is the notation for the service call. in the services.yml

Comment: Seems the culprit was a very unorthodox Guzzle implementation of a former colleague. 
I will now start a major round of refactoring and that should solve the problem.